# Sending JSON GET Request to API ,Error 500

Tags: flutter, api, http, model

plz Can someone help me !!,i get error when i call the data from json api, When i test my api in Postman, everything works fine, but as soon as I run the code, I receive the following error:
i think the error cause of when i declare the list carslist, i think it's not true:  `List<CarWasher> carsList = [];`

[image]

this is my model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

CarWasher emptyFromJson(String str) => CarWasher.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String emptyToJson(CarWasher data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CarWasher {
  CarWasher({
    required this.now,
    required this.bookings,
  });

  Now now;
  List<Now> bookings;

  factory CarWasher.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CarWasher(
    now: Now.fromJson(json["now"]),
    bookings: List<Now>.from(json["bookings"].map((x) => Now.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "now": now.toJson(),
    "bookings": List<dynamic>.from(bookings.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Now {
  Now({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.bookingTypeId,
    required this.carWasherId,
    required this.buildingId,
    required this.serviceId,
    required this.packageId,
    required this.vehiculeId,
    this.tookenPackageId,
    required this.status,
    required this.dateTime,
    required this.date,
    this.address,
    required this.longitude,
    required this.latitude,
    this.rate,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
    required this.location,
    required this.duration,
    required this.start,
    required this.end,
  });

  int id;
  int userId;
  int bookingTypeId;
  int carWasherId;
  int buildingId;
  int serviceId;
  int packageId;
  int vehiculeId;
  dynamic tookenPackageId;
  String status;
  DateTime dateTime;
  DateTime date;
  dynamic address;
  double longitude;
  double latitude;
  dynamic rate;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;
  String location;
  int duration;
  String start;
  String end;

  factory Now.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Now(
    id: json["id"],
    userId: json["userId"],
    bookingTypeId: json["bookingTypeId"],
    carWasherId: json["carWasherId"],
    buildingId: json["buildingId"],
    serviceId: json["serviceId"],
    packageId: json["packageId"] == null ? null : json["packageId"],
    vehiculeId: json["vehiculeId"],
    tookenPackageId: json["tookenPackageId"],
    status: json["status"],
    dateTime: DateTime.parse(json["dateTime"]),
    date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
    address: json["address"],
    longitude: json["longitude"] == null ? null : json["longitude"].toDouble(),
    latitude: json["latitude"] == null ? null : json["latitude"].toDouble(),
    rate: json["rate"],
    createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
    updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    location: json["location"],
    duration: json["duration"],
    start: json["start"],
    end: json["end"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "userId": userId,
    "bookingTypeId": bookingTypeId,
    "carWasherId": carWasherId,
    "buildingId": buildingId,
    "serviceId": serviceId,
    "packageId": packageId == null ? null : packageId,
    "vehiculeId": vehiculeId,
    "tookenPackageId": tookenPackageId,
    "status": status,
    "dateTime": dateTime.toIso8601String(),
    "date": "${date.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${date.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${date.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
    "address": address,
    "longitude": longitude == null ? null : longitude,
    "latitude": latitude == null ? null : latitude,
    "rate": rate,
    "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
    "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
    "location": location,
    "duration": duration,
    "start": start,
    "end": end,
  };
}
```

this is my http function:

```
Future<List<CarWasher>> _getCarWasher() async {
    var  value = await token_read();
    String url = "xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxx";

      final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url),headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Authorization' :'Bearer $value',
      });

       print("Status Code: ${response.statusCode}");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        final jsonItems = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

        List<CarWasher> carsList = jsonItems.map<CarWasher>((json) {
          return CarWasher.fromJson(json);
        }).toList();

        print(carsList.length);
        print(carsList[0].now.location);
        return carsList;

      } else {
        throw Exception("Unable to retrieve data.");
      }
  }
```

i think this is the cause:

[image]

Comment: 500 status code is server error this has nothing to do with your code as far as i know. Since your _getCarWasher function is not returning the List<Carwasher> value you are getting the error in HomePageState. Check if you are using the correct URL.

Comment: the URL is correct, when i test my api in postman everything works fine, the function return Future<List<CarWasher>> is it correct !!

Comment: Yeah. Can you just type a sample url which you are using. This 500 error has to be mostly wth your URL

Comment: the API you are calling is accept GET method for sure?

Comment: yes, sure 100%.